# How do I use light, normal, semibold, and bold font types in one document using sourcesanspro font?

Tags: fontspec, bold, sourcesanspro

How do I use light, normal, semibold, and bold font types in one document using sourcesanspro font? If I specify the default options, I can get normal and bold, but not light or semibold. If I use the light option, I can get light and semibold, but not normal or bold.

A MWE is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[default% with default, I can get normal and bold, but not light and semibold
%, light% If I add this line, I can get light and semibold, but not normal and bold
]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}

How do I get all these types of text in one document on demand?

\begin{itemize}
    \item light %how?
    \item \textmd{normal}
    \item semibold %how?
    \item \textbf{bold}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264275, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404395, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374121?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sourcesanspro` package (see [documentation](https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcesanspro/blob/master/doc/latex/sourcesanspro/sourcesanspro.pdf)) also provides commands to select a certain set of fonts for convenience:

- `\sourcesanspro` for the regular and bold weigths
- `\sourcesansprolight` for light and semibold
- `\sourcesansproextreme` for extra light and black

The following also produces what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{document}

How do I get all these types of text in one document on demand?

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textmd{\sourcesansproextreme extra light}
    \item \textmd{\sourcesansprolight   light}
    \item \textmd{\sourcesanspro        normal}
    \item \textbf{\sourcesansprolight   semibold}
    \item \textbf{\sourcesanspro        bold}
    \item \textbf{\sourcesansproextreme black}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The `\sourcesanspro` isn't really necessary, of course.

[image: code rendering]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Therese](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7883/th%c3%a9r%c3%a8se), I found my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264265/defining-subfamilies-for-a-font/264275#264275). As a novice, I didn't realize that `\usepackage{sourcesanspro}` downloads the fonts to they are callable as shown in the working code below. I also had to remove the options I had defined when calling `\usepackage`. The working code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[%default% including default overrides the \setmainfont below.
%, light% 
]{sourcesanspro}

% Found answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264265/defining-subfamilies-for-a-font/264275#264275

\setmainfont{SourceSansPro}[ %list of fonts included in sourcesanspro package are listed here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/sourcesanspro/doc/sourcesanspro.tex
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-RegularIt,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt,
  FontFace={xl}{n}{*-ExtraLight},
  FontFace={xl}{it}{*-ExtraLightIt},
  FontFace={l}{n}{*-Light},
  FontFace={l}{it}{*-LightIt},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{*-Semibold},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{*-SemiboldIt},
  FontFace={k}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace={k}{it}{*-BlackIt},
]

\newcommand{\test}[2]{%
  #1: {\fontseries{#2}\selectfont This is upright. \itshape This is italic}\par
}

\begin{document}

I can now get all these types of text in one document on demand.
\vspace{\baselineskip}


\test{ExtraLight}{xl}
\test{Light}{l}
\test{Regular}{m}
\test{Medium}{mb}
\test{Bold}{bx}
\test{Black}{k}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: XeLaTeX compile]

Comment: I have submitted [an issue](https://github.com/silkeh/latex-sourcesanspro/issues/7) to implement `FontFace` in the `sourcesanspro` package. Though the names will probably match the Type1 fonts.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was more concise than mine, so I've marked it as the answer.